# ¿Cómo abrir una carpeta local desde intranet HTML?

Tags: html, web

Necesito abrir la carpeta "D:/musica" desde el explorador de windows (por fuera del navegador) que está en mi computador desde un botón de una página web

Comment: Una cosa es mostrar el dialogo para que el usuario navegue sus directorios, y otra es guardar ese directorio, eso último no se puede desde el cliente, por suerte.

Comment: Hola, eso es lo que necesito, que el usuario pueda abrir una carpeta de su pc desde el navegador pero no sé como puedo hacerlo